# How to check RDS MySQL database synchronization status

Tags: replication, amazon-rds, master-slave-replication

We were creating a read replica for an RDS MySQL (5.7.28) instance, and before the read replica became available one of our developer accidentally connected to the read replica and was able to write to the read replica (though the read replica should have prevented any writing operation). Later on he discovered the master instance and the read replica were out of sync since the read replica had the record while the master instance didn't.

We are wondering if there is a way to check the synchronization status between the master and read replica. We have explored 3rd party options such as `mysqlrplsync` from mysql-utilities and `pt-table-checksum` from Percona toolkits but they require the database user to have `SUPER` privilege, which RDS does not grant. Is there an RDS native tool to perform such a check?

Thank you.